# Scroll on website on iPhone 7 is slow and static

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The scroll is very slow and static when in Safari, on iPhone 7. There is no flow after scrolling, it just stops immediately when you lift your finger off of the screen.

There is also an issue where i can't double click the clock/URL bar, to get back to the top of the page. If i see other pages the URL bar hides when you are scrolling down the page - but it doesn't on my site.

I'm not sure as to what causes these issues, but my guess would be either HTML, CSS or JavaScript. You can see the issue here: http://www.shareone.dk/ using iPhone

Comment: try removing html {overflow:hidden} rule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use an overflow. For make you scroll smooth use this:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

See more details here : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/